# How to inject repository in a C# IComparer class?

Tags: c#, icomparer

I need to sort questions by its sort order.

One table named **Questions** stores the sort order info in **QuestionId** and **SortOrder**.

The other table **ApplicantQuestions** contains all the questions and answers, referencing the first table by **QuestionId**.

So basically we want to sort a list based on another list.

```
public class QuestionOrderComparer : IComparer<int>
{
    private readonly IRepository<Question> _Questions;

    public QuestionOrderComparer(IRepository<Question> Questions)
    {
        _Questions = Questions;
    }

    public int Compare(int x, int y)
    {
        var questionsInOrder = _Questions.All
            .Select(q => new QuestionOrderModel(q.QuestionId, q.SortOrder))
            .ToList();

        var xValue = questionsInOrder.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == x)?.SortOrder ?? 0;
        var yValue = questionsInOrder.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == y)?.SortOrder ?? 0;
        return xValue - yValue;
    }
}
```

That looks fine, but when I try to use it

```
thisSetOfApplicantQuestions
    .OrderBy(x => x.QuestionId, new QuestionOrderComparer());
```

the intellisense requires me to add some parameter for `IRepository<Question>`.

How to deal with that? Is it possible to have injection inside an `IComparer` class?

Comment: Your constructor requires an `IRepository<Question>` parameter. You need to pass one into the constructor.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be automatically resolved by my StructureMap?

Comment: Doesn't the class calling `OrderBy` already have an injected `IRepository` instance? If you are using pure DI (i.e. have a composition root where everything is injected), then all dependencies should be injected through constructors and passed along deeper to inner classes. Otherwise, you can use a service locator to resolve the comparer (which is not pure DI, however).

Comment: @Groo, I hope the questions standard order constructed into the `IComparer` class. The caller only has `IRepository<ApplicantQuestion>`. Not `IRepository<Question>`.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is the caller should simply have a `IRepository<Question>` parameter in its constructor, along `IRepo<ApplicantQuestion>`. But one rather strange thing is that each call to `Compare` seems to fetch the entire `Questions` table, on each call (presuming you are using EF or NHibernate under the hood). Doesn't your ORM support automatic LINQ-to-DB joins? I.e. simply `.OrderBy(x => x.ParentQuestion.SortOrder)`, where `ParentQuestion` is mapped through the ORM to point to the right `Question` instance? This would convert the entire query to a single DB select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about hiding repository behind factory? Structure map will resolve everything for you.

```
public class QuestionOrderComparerFactory : IQuestionOrderComparerFactory
    {
        private IRepository<Question> _questions;

        public QuestionOrderComparerFactory(IRepository<Question> questions)
        {
            _questions = questions;
        }

        public QuestionOrderComparer Create()
        {
            return new QuestionOrderComparer(_questions);
        }

    }



    thisSetOfApplicantQuestions.OrderBy(x => x.QuestionId, _comparerFactory.Create()); // comparer factory is injected via constructor
```

Btw I wouldn't put this logic in a comparer unless you want to reuse it in many places. I always thought of using comparer in very simple cases without any external dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Dump the comparer and put that code in a `Sort` method in a questions collection object.

This code is conflating comparing and sorting. Traditionally a class overrides `CompareTo`, or has a customer comparer. The .net framework knows to use this when calling `sort` on a collection of questions.  A "compare" method should be comparing - returning -1,0,1 (less than, equal, greater than, respectively) - not doing the actual sorting. I can see LINQ changing that paradigm, but still, `Compare` doing sorting seems to be working against the framework. Then, the `Questions` collection should have-a comparer, not vice versa.